# Intl formatRange outputs slash instead of Japanese year, month, day literals

Tags: javascript, date, internationalization

Is there any way to configure [`formatRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatRange) or [`formatRangeToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatRangeToParts) to produce the same **literals** as [`format`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/format) and [`formatToParts`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/formatToParts) does when using Japanese `ja` locale?

I was hoping to get something like `2022年7月13日 ~ 2022年7月14日` but the range methods produce a `/` literal instead of the Japanese characters, resulting in `2022/07/13～2022/07/14`. Maybe the *range format* is correct for Japanese readers/speakers?

```js
const
  options = { month: 'short', day: 'numeric', year: 'numeric' } 
, from    = new Date('2022-07-13T12:00:00Z')
, to      = new Date('2022-07-14T12:00:00Z')
, withLiterals     = Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja', options).format(from)
, withSlashLiteral = Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja', options).formatRange(from, to)
, singleDateParts  = Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja', options).formatToParts(from)
, rangeParts       = Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja', options).formatRangeToParts(from, to)
, onlyLiterals     = ({ type, value }) => type === 'literal' ? value : ''

console.log('format\t\t\t= working literals\t', withLiterals)
console.log('formatRange\t\t= slash literals\t', withSlashLiteral)
console.log('formatToParts\t\t= working literals\t', singleDateParts.map(onlyLiterals).join(''))
console.log('formatRangeToParts\t= slash literals\t', rangeParts.map(onlyLiterals).join(''))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important;top: 0;}
.as-console-row::after {display: none !important;}
```

Comment: FireFox make a différent result than Chrome...

Comment: I guess it might be a JavaScript engine problem if Firefox is different to Chrome (and node)

Comment: Worth repeating that the *Intl* object is not meant to be prescriptive with formats, indeed implementation dependent behaviour is expected (perhaps even encouraged). So do not use it if you need consistent, precise formatting in a variety of unknown hosts.

Comment: @RobG very interesting! I assumed the output would be prescribed as the standard for each locale

Comment: @andyb—for [*toLocaleString* ECMA-262](https://262.ecma-international.org/#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring) says ["use ECMA-402"](https://402.ecma-international.org/9.0/#sec-intl.datetimeformat-internal-slots), which, for language specific formatting, says "use the [CLDR](https://cldr.unicode.org/)". E.g. [formatting data for German (de)](https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=de) and [en-gb](https://icu4c-demos.unicode.org/icu-bin/locexp?d_=en&_=en-gb).